Thevenized Resistance
Would anyone be able to guide me in setting up this thevenized circuit? I have researched/viewed a variety of videos/lectures and i cannot wrap my brain around this theory. I would greatly appreciate any resources to learn more about it as well. The answer per the key should be 194.8677. But I haven't be able to get close to jt.

You need to show us your work so that we can see which part you have a problem with.

I have added a quick mock up of the answer I keep getting. Thank you for your input.

From what I see you did not disconnect (remove) the load resistance from the circuit.
Because we want to find the resistance seen by the load resistance. This is why we need to remove it from the circuit.
The first step:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Nex we turn off the voltage source (VS = 0V). So now we can replace it with a wire (short circuit).

simulate this circuit
We can further simplify the circuit. Just by notice that now R1 and R2 are also shorted by the "wire" that remained after the voltage source.
Therefore we left with this circuit:

simulate this circuit
Now you should be able to find Rth without any problems.
Any additional qestions?

Thank you so much ! This helped me out a lot ! I appreciate it!

@Saho If it was helpful then can you vote on the answer, and maybe also accept it (click the checkmark next to the voting arrows)?
